# Using ObjectMapper - How to JSON result into a TableView swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, objectmapper

I have problem passing my JSON result into a array I use for display in a TableView.

here my model:

```
class Restaurant: Mappable {

var lat: Float?
var lng: Float?
var address: String?
var name: String?

required init?(_ map: Map) { }

// Mappable
func mapping(map: Map) {
    lat     <- map["venue.location.lat"]
    lng     <- map["venue.location.lng"]
    address <- map["venue.location.address"]
    name    <- map["venue.name"]
}
}
```

and here my ViewController

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var listRestaurants: [Restaurant] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
retrieveFoursquareList()
tableView.reloadData()
}

func retrieveFoursquareList(){
let foursquareService = FoursquareService()

foursquareService.getFoursquare {
  (let response) in

  if let currrently = response {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      print("RESULTADO 2 array: \(currrently)")

      for restaurant in currrently {
        if let name = restaurant.name {
          restaurant.name = name
          print("RESULTADO 3 row: \(restaurant.name)")
          self.listRestaurants.append(restaurant)
          print("RESULTADO 4 array: \(self.listRestaurants)")

        }

      } 
    }
  }
} 
}
}

extension ListViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->    Int {
return listRestaurants.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RestautantsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RestaurantCell


let listRestaurant = listRestaurants[indexPath.row]

cell.nameLabel.text = listRestaurant.name
cell.addressLabel.text = listRestaurant.address
return cell
}

}
```

In the image you can see that my JSON result is OK. My problem is how to pass this result into de var listRestaurant array:

[JSON output is OK but I have problem passing this JSON into the var listRestaurant array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS5Fq.png)

I will appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are setting the tableview delegate,

in your viewDidLoad, add the following code:

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

This code:

```
for restaurant in currrently {
    if let name = restaurant.name {
      restaurant.name = name
```

you are also setting the restaurant name to the restaurant name, I see no benefit to this line, if you just want to check that the name is set before you add it, do:

```
if let _ = restaurant.name {
    self.listRestaurants.append(restaurant)
}
```

The mapping you are using, I am not familiar with, so I'm not sure about this one, but the documentation [here](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) (if this is what you are using) suggests that you create an object like this:

```
let restaurant = Mapper<Restaurant>().map(restaurantData)
```

I'm not sure you can just cast it in the way that you are, but, I am not sure.

The main reason your tableView is not displaying is because of the delegate functions are not set.

Comment: Thanks for the delegates. I fixed it. But I have still problem with passing data. I used let restaurant = Mapper<Restaurant>().map(restaurantData) what it doesn't work.